# How to put space before the for loop?... Python

Tags: python

**How to put space before the for loop?**

**My Input:**

```
for i in range(0,6):
    print(i, end=" ")
print()
print("0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
```

**Result:**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

**How can i make it like this?:**

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Something like `print(" ", end=" ")` would be the obvious solution.

Comment: For any arbitrary length, you could take the difference in length of your string and the length of the string with all zeros. You'd then pad with spaces by that amount. Or just right align the string if you wanted it to be formatted in the console.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Just need to tell the loop to make a space instead of writing the number

```
print(" ", end=" ")
for i in range(0,6):
        print(i, end=" ")
print()
print("0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
```

OR

```
for i in range(0,6):
    if i == 0:
        print(" ", end=" ")
        print("0", end=" ")
    else:
        print(i, end=" ")
print()
print("0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
```

Output:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Why not just put the print before the loop instead of checking if `== 0` every iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply print an empty space before your loop.

```py
print(" ", end=" ")
for i in range(0, 6):
    print(i, end=" ")
print()
print("0 0 0 0 0 0 0")
```

Outputs:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print('  ', end='')
[print(i, end=' ') for i in range(6)]
print('\n0 0 0 0 0 0 0')
```

Output:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Python Data-frame, Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

L = []

for i in range(0, 6):
    L.append(i)

df = pd.DataFrame([
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   ], columns=[L])

print(df)
```